# How to suspend and resume adControl at windows phone 8.1 JS App?

Tags: javascript, html, windows-phone-8.1

MSDN says that I can do it like this:

```
this.adControl = new Microsoft.Advertising.WinRT.UI.AdControl();
this.adControl.suspend();
```

But when I try, I get "Unable to get property 'UI' of undefined or null reference".

My ad banner works ok. It displays advertisements, but I can't suspend and resume it. MSDN says that I have to do this, when I want to hide/display the banner. Hidding banners without suspending is incorrect.

Comment: Wouldn't you want to find the ad control on the page instead of creating a new one to suspend?

Comment: @KenTucker, How? It's just a `div` element on my page. It can't have `suspend` and `resume` methods.